# Frechet Bounds inequality

Tags: statistics, data-mining, probability, intersection, inequalities

In the Frechet Bounds inequality equation,

`max(0, P(A) + P(B) − 1) ≤ P(A & B) ≤ min(P(A), P(B))`

I can totally understand the intuition behind the minimum value of `P(A & B)` to be "0" and maximum value to be minimum of "P(A) and P(B)" but in what possible case will the minimum value be `P(A)+ P(B)-1`?

According to my understanding, the maximum value of `P(A)+P(B)` can be 1 or less than 1. So `P(A)+P(B) -1` will always be "0" or negative. In what possible way, `P(A) +P(B)-1` will be greater than "0"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`P(AUB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A&B)`, by the union rule.

`=> P(A&B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(AUB) >= P(A)+P(B)-1`, since `P(AUB) <= 1`, being a probability measure. (1)

Also, `P(A&B) >= 0`, being a probability measure. (2)

Combining (1) & (2), `P(A&B) >=  max(0,P(A)+P(B)-1)`

Consider the following 2 cases in the following figure:
[image]

Comment: Thanks much for the explanation